# VueJS - Binding custom prop doesn't work with b-form component

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I follow this [vue doc](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html) to create a custom component with a custom attribute like this:

```
    Vue.component('y-form-checkbox', {
    props: ['chkLabel'],
    template: `<b-form-group label="label">
                <b-form-checkbox>
                  {{ chkLabel }}
                </b-form-checkbox>
            </b-form-group>`
    });
```

And then I use this component like following:

```
<y-form-checkbox chkLabel="Something special"></y-form-checkbox>
```

But the problem is that the chkLabel doesn't bind to the component's template as expected. I just got a checkbox without label. Why this happens? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the **`cabab-case`** format instead of the **`camelCase`** one when dealing wthi props :

```
 <y-form-checkbox chk-label="Something special"></y-form-checkbox>
```

and keep it in  **`camelCase`** format in component props declaration :

```
  Vue.component('y-form-checkbox', {
    props: ['chkLabel'],
    template: `<b-form-group label="label">
                <b-form-checkbox>
                  {{ chkLabel }}
                </b-form-checkbox>
            </b-form-group>`
    });
```